# Is it possible to monitor all network traffic from an iOS app from within the app?

Tags: ios

I would like to track the times that network requests occur as well as their size, from within  an iOS app. Is there a way to do this (without private APIs)?

I am writing a static library which will be included in an app whose code I have access to. However, I want to minimize the amount of modifications I make to the app's code. Assume the network requests (HTTP only) can be sent anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Are you writing the app? Whose network? where are the requests going? What does your app do? For your device only? (The questions go on and on and on...)

Comment: If you need more information comment on my answer and I'll get back to you.

Comment: added more info to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free and open-source library: https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy
Really easy to integrate and to use, using Cocoapods.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the creator of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to monitor all network traffic within your own app by measuring every up/download you send or receive. You will not be able to monitor traffic outside of your application.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Some objective-c code would be great.

Comment: When you use Core Foundation networking, or other networking frameworks, measure the size of the request and measure the size of the raw result you get back. Start by looking into CFHTTPMessage.

If you want to measure the entire bandwidth, download [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and then point your iPhone proxy settings to it. Charles will show you all the HTTP requests' headers and request body. It can even handle SSL requests.

Comment: Is it possible to do this via a category? The app in question uses NSURLConnection to do http requests.